# How to use more than one Constant Timer with different values in one Thread Group?

Tags: performance, timer, jmeter

I'm trying to run a test by the following **scenario**:

1. 500 users try to login to the server for 2,5 hours.
2. After login they start to send 2 different types of requests to server and logout at the same time.
3. After they logout process begins, they immediately start to login again.

This whole thing has the following **parameters**:

- 1 login happens every 8,5 sec;
- 1-st type of request happens every 15 sec;
- 2-nd type of request happens every 10 sec;
- logout happens every 8,5 sec.

I've tried to use Throuput Controller, but it works for all Thread Group.
Also I've tried to use IF Controllers with Groovy timer, but Groovy timer doesn't work.

**Expected result:**

- 1 login happens every 8,5 sec;
- 1-st type of request happens every 15 sec;
- 2-nd type of request happens every 10 sec;
- logout happens every 8,5 sec.

**Actual result:**

- first 2.5 hours the login is executed every 8,5 sec;
- when the requests phase begins, timers for logins and logouts don't work correctly;
- timers for 2 types of requests don't work correctly too.